# FB.logout() called without an access token error

Tags: facebook, logout

I have upgraded my js FB Connect to oauth version & when I am trying to logout from FB programatically using FB.logout() method, I am getting error like

"FB.logout() called without an access token"

What is the problem behind this? I saw one [thread](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8430474/fb-logout-called-without-an-access-token) over here but it didn't worked for me. Please help me if someone has found solution for this. Thanks.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  Allow user to Connect. If no page refresh occurs, user can logout with FB.logout, and it works correctly.   However, after page is reloaded once, FB.logout will trigger a console warning: "FB.logout() called without an access token"

Answer (score 9):

This is what i've used before.

```
//check if logout is 
FB.getLoginStatus(function(ret) {
    /// are they currently logged into Facebook?
    if(ret.authResponse) {
        //they were authed so do the logout
        FB.logout(function(response) {
           //do your stuff here.
        });
    } else {
       ///do something if they aren't logged in
       //or just get rid of this if you don't need to do something if they weren't logged in
    }
});
```

Comment: good one! how/where to add redirection after logout? tried to add in FB.logout(function(response) { ...  but in that case i'm not logged out. can you help please?

Comment: It's not clear from the documentation, but you need to call things like FB.login as a callback from other functions.  This one being getLoginStatus.  On the documentation is shows it being called just on it's own.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this problem and fixed it.

This happened for me when a user had already logged out and I tried to fb.logout() method again. It seems in the following code:

```
FB.logout(function(response)
  {
     console.log(response.status);
  }
);
```

`response.status` will say 'connected' even if the user is logged out, due to some caching issues or some other bug. Hence its better to use `authResponse` to determine whether or not the user is logged in. I.e:

```
FB.logout(function(response)
  {
     if (! response.authResponse)
       //disable logout button
  }
);
```

Comment: yeah this is the right approach it worked for me albeit slightly modified, but the idea was same. I have upvoted. Thanks

Comment: this does not solve the problem of facebook complaining of a missing access token